# How do I read data from text file to ArrayList

Tags: java

Assume that entered file have the following data:

```
101 
alice
102
bob
103
smith
```

All this data into textfile, as it's shown in program, just enter text file name and read all data and display.

I wanna read those two data (number and name ) into `ArrayList` and display all the data as what I've shown in the program:

```
class Student {
    private int num;
    private String name;

    public Student(int num, String name) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[ student number :: "+num+" ] \t [ student name :: 
               "+name+ "]";
    }
}


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Tester {
    public static void main(String [] aa)throws IOException {
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" enter file name >> ");
        String filename=kb.nextLine();

        File f = new File(filename);
        kb=new Scanner(f);

        ArrayList<Student> stu =new ArrayList<Student>();

        while(kb.hasNextLine()) {
            int num=kb.nextInt();kb.nextLine();
            String name =kb.nextLine();

            stu.add(num);
            stu.add(name);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<stu.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(stu.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all data stored in the file with separate line

Answer (score 0):

Since you already made an arraylist of student you can do this inside your text reader(while loop): stu.add(new Student(num, name)); what it does is you are creating an object of student and placing it inside the arraylist for every record in your text file.

Answer (score 0):

Your program should return an error because are attempting to put a `String` and `int` into an `ArrayList` of Students. Also, you only iterates through your `ArrayList` of students and do not print them out. Your code should look like this.

```
class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] aa) throws IOException {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" enter file name >> ");
        String filename = kb.nextLine();

        File f = new File(filename);
        kb = new Scanner(f);

        ArrayList<Student> stu = new ArrayList<Student>();

        while (kb.hasNextLine()) {
            int num = kb.nextInt();
            kb.nextLine();
            String name = kb.nextLine();

            stu.add(new Student(num, name));
        }

        for (Student s : stu) {
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file looks like this 
101 alice 
102 bob 
103 smith

```
String fileName = //get by scanner;

//read file into stream, try-with-resources
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    List<Student> users = new ArrayList<>();
    stream.stream().forEach(user -> {
        List<String> userAttrs = Arrays.asList(user.split("\\s* \\s*"));
        Student userObj = new Student(Integer.parseInt(userAttrs.get(0)), userAttrs.get(1));
        users.add(userObj);
    });

    users.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After I enter first answer problem was edited and now your file looks like 
 
101 
alice 
 
102 
bob 
 
103 
smith

```
String fileName = //get by scanner;

//read file into stream, try-with-resources
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    List<String> detailList = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    BiFunction<String, String, Student> userFunction = (id, name) -> 
                                 new Student(Integer.parseInt(id), name);

        for (int i = 0; i < detailList.size(); i += 2) {
            students.add(userFunction.apply(
                       detailList.get(i), detailList.get(i+1)));
        }
        students.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {        

    String path = "E:\\b.txt";

    Tester tester = new Tester();

    String[] str = tester.sortData(tester.readFile(path));

    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

    for(int i = 0;i < str.length;i = i + 2){
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setNum(Integer.parseInt(str[i]));
        student.setName(str[i + 1]);

        list.add(student);
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getNum() + " " + list.get(i).getName());
    }

}

public StringBuilder readFile(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String lineTxt = null;

        while((lineTxt = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(lineTxt);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("erro");
    }

    return stringBuilder;
}

public String[] sortData(StringBuilder words){
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String str = "\\d+.\\d+|\\w+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(str); 
    Matcher ma = pattern.matcher(words);

    String[] data = new String[6];

    while(ma.find()){
        data[i] = ma.group();
        i++;
    }

    return data;
}
```

}

class Student{

```
private int num;
private String name;

public Student(){

}

public Student(int num, String name) {
    super();
    this.num = num;
    this.name = name;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Student [num=" + num + ", name=" + name + "]";
}

public int getNum() {
    return num;
}
public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}